# Google Calendar Events disable reminders and notifications via API, overriding user's default settings

Tags: google-calendar-api

I would like to insert an event into my app users' Google Calendars. I want to disable the reminders and notifications, overriding their settings if any.

I have set the `reminders.useDefault` to `false`, and I have set the `sendNotifications` to `false`.

However, the reminders are still getting issued.

How can I disable them?

[Link to Google Calendar API event insert reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: When I tried inserting an event into the calendar with sendNotifications to false, invitee didn't get the notification about the invitation even though invitees calendar UI has New events setting to "true". Try your request in the google API explorer, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: Yes, what you describe is what I want. Did you set the `reminders.useDefault` at all?